# Dividing an integer into lists

Tags: python, counter

I want to make a counter such that there are 3 values in a list counting up at different intervals. For example, list [0, 0, 0] should count up like this [0, 0, 1] => [0, 0, 2] => [0,0,3] until there is "999" in each index [999,999,999].

When the list[2] reaches 999, list[1] should go up by 1 and start counting from zero.

This is what I have:

```
thisList = ["%03d" % x for x in range(1000)] #produces a list of increasing numbers
trueList = []

for i in range(0, len(thisList)):
  trueList.append([int(d) for d in str(thisList[i])]) #Divides the list into each of the individual integers

print(trueList)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't quite understand what your code tries to do. Could you try commenting it ?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: "Any suggestions?" is too broad for Stack Overflow.  If you want a code review, then post to that site.  If you have a problem with this code, supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).

Comment: @Prune Noted. I'm new to the website and will do my research, thanks either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `itertools.product`:

```
trueList = list(product(range(1000), repeat=3))
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! I should read the itertools documentation in depth since it's really useful. I'll accept the answer asap

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this without itertools:

```
counter = ( [n//1000000,(n//1000%1000),n%1000] for n in range(1000**3) )

# counter will contain the same output as itertools.product(range(1000), repeat=3)

for c in counter: print(c)

[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 2]
[0, 0, 3]
[0, 0, 4]
...
[0, 0, 998]
[0, 0, 999]
[0, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 2]
...
[0, 999, 998]
[0, 999, 999]
[1, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 2]
```